# Xamarin.Forms Editor HeightRequest in a TableView

Tags: android, layout, tableview, xamarin.forms

New in Xamarin.Forms, working on VS Community 2015, building an app to Android Lollipop simulator. 
I´m trying to insert an Editor into a TableView, this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
 <ContentPage.Content>
  <StackLayout>
   <TableView x:Name="table" Intent="Form">
    <TableRoot>
     <TableSection Title="My note">
      <ViewCell>
       <StackLayout>
        <Editor BackgroundColor="#FFFF8D"
                HeightRequest="200"
                Text="Text on Yellow background" />
       </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
     </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
   </TableView>
  </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Building for Android, HeightRequest does not work. Just one Editor line is showing.

It works perfectly *without* the TableView structure (no tableView, Root, Section and inner StackLayout)
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to set the HasUnevenRows property to true for the TableView.  That will allow the rows to fully enclose the editor (not just the first line).

Comment: Thanks, @LyndonHughey ! Works perfectly!